# What does this mean? "Represent the scatter plot for the dependent and independent variables for each data category."

Tags: r, data-visualization

So I am working on the esoph dataset that is provided by default in RStudio. The data set explores correlations between age, smoking, drinking and oesophageal cancer.

One of the questions we have to ask ourselves as part of our statistics lecture is the question mentioned above. We are studying bivariate distribution.

Does the data category corresponds to each subgroups of the columns? For instance for tobgp :

- 0-9
- 10-19
- 20-29
- 30+

Should I plot ncases with all agegp's subgroups ? Same with alcgp, tobgp, ncontrols ?

Dependent variable:

- Ncases

Independent variables:

- Agegp
- Alcgp
- Tobgp
- Ncontrols

Is this correct?

```
par(mfrow=c(3,2))
for(group in levels(esoph$agegp))
  plot(esoph$ncases[esoph$agegp==group], main=paste("Agegp = ", group),
       xlim=c(0, 18))
```

Comment: Is there a statistical question hidden in there or is this about `R` syntax only?

Comment: You should know, because this forum is only about statistics questions, not about using statistics programs. Cf https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would do it

[image]

Code for the plot

```
library(tidyverse)


data("esoph")

esoph %>% 
  mutate(p = ncases/(ncases+ncontrols)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(tobgp, p, color = agegp))+
  geom_point()+
  facet_wrap(~alcgp)
```

I think it is reasonable to say that tobacco consumption is the primary variable of interest here, so it makes sense to put that on the x axis.  The remaining aesthetics I suppose could be permuted.  Nothing special about coloring by age.

Comment: Does that mean that someone who is 25-34 years old who smokes 0-9g/day and drinks 0-39g/day has zero chances of getting oesophagael cancer? And someone who drinks 0-39g/day and smokes 30+/day who is between 55-64 years old is the most likely to get cancer?